# Planning view component in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I need to build a Swing GUI like this
[GUI Mockup http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/7271/mockupl.png](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/7271/mockupl.png)
where there are typically 40 tour columns. In each column there are typically up to 20 orders per tour. Orders may be grouped together within a tour. It should be possible to horizontally enlarge to columns, to D&D orders within a tour and to other tours. Later the representation might change including e.g. images.

I once did something similar using JTable, but for this task I think a JTable is not the right solution. And because of the grouping of orders there are no real rows.

Thought #1:
I thought of using a JPanel, a LayoutManager (or NullLayout) and JComponents for this, but I am not sure if this is the way to go.

Thought #2:
Another possibility is to use a JPanel (in a scrollpanel), set it's size to correct value, override paintComponent, and paint everything myself (maybe by using an approach like TableCellRenderer for not needing to paint *everything* myself -- i.e. using *one* renderer per type to render, set it's values, use Graphics.translate and then component.paint...)

In both approaches I need to implement the D&D code myself, #1 would make it possible to use the JComponents D&D implementation, but this wouldn't be that hard in #2 either. Inserting and removing of orders in #2 seems easier, since in #1 some LayoutManager (or in case of NullLayout all elements below) are involved, otherwise only a repaint is necessary. #1 might be a memory problem when that many JComponents are created, and the initial add(component) seems to be somewhat costly in my first tests.

What do you think? How would you implement this? Or maybe is there some library for swing to create such a panel?

Comment: What do you mean by D&D?

Comment: With D&D i mean Drag and Drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to expand on Thought #1:
you could do this with a succession of JPanels.  Your parent JPanel would layout a set of Tour panels in fixed width columns.  the Tour classes could be panels that contain a TourHeader panel and a set of ItineraryItem panels.  This might be heavier weight, but potentially easier for others to follow.

you could also reconsider the JTable option.  take a look at some of the JTable examples on [this ancient site](http://www.crionics.com/products/opensource/faq/swing_ex/SwingExamples.html) for some ideas for cells spanning rows.

Answer (score 2):

The approach #1 should work. I did it several times.

But if you want to make your drag and drop simpler I would suggest using JLists(without scroll panes) for your orders. You will be able to implement D&D within lists as well as between them if needed. To customize how order looks you can use renderers. On top of lists you can use panels or labels as tour headers.

So I would create specialized TourView component with header on top and JList on the bottom. Then add many of TourViews to panel as you thought in case #1.

In all cases, except when using JTable, you have to implement column enlarging  yourself.

Comment: +1 for the idea of using a JList. This seems to be a nice idea and I will definitely try it.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, I think a use of the Infonode library (Docking Windows) could help, it includes D&D, you could move panels easily.
The only problem with it would be to "force" it, for example using one RootWindow (the base component per Tour, i'm not sure.

Infonode is a GPL library, for commercial use, there is a commercial license too, depending on your need.

For information, i'm not related to them, but I use this framework, and I like it, and it could be a solution, maybe

http://www.infonode.net/index.html?idwdemo (check demo)

Comment: +1 for the hint on docking frameworks. I will evaluate if using a docking framework (not necessary infonode, but it looks nice) for this task.

Answer (score 0):

both approaches are feasable though i would probably rule out #2 on account of it being difficult to implement.

if i went route 1 I'd probably try something like FlowlLayout with some JPanels but in the past I've never really gotten decent results from trying to get things to the size I really want them, usually layout managers like to size everything for you.